# How to display rows that have more than two Column Row values in common with Power Bi Dax?

Tags: python, powerbi, dax

I have table called **'Marks'**, there are columns named **'ChildId','Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'** and onwards.
My goal is to make a **new column** only identifying if the child **Failed or Passed** the semester. where a child will fail a semester if he/she **failed more than 2 tests**.

For example if the the child nr.5 failed only Test 1 but pass the rest then that new column value will show pass. But where child nr.6 failed Test 1, test 2 and test 3 so his new column value at the end will show Failed.

Here is my idea in python pseudo, I would like to convert this to Power Bi Dax but not sure how that would look. Any help would be appreciated.

```
            var = count(test1==Failed or test2==Failed or .... testn==Failed)
               if var >= 2:
                  markval = Failed
               else:
                  markval= Pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean values like `Marks[Test1] = "Failed"` are evaluated to 0/1, so you could use simple sum, e.g.

```
Column = IF(
    (Marks[Test1] = "Failed") + (Marks[Test2] = "Failed") + (Marks[Test3] = "Failed") >= 2, 
    "Failed", 
    "Passed"
)
```

Comment: Please change ">=2" to ">". Then your code is OKAY.

Answer (score 1):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUXJLzMxJTQEyAhKLizEoVNlYnWglI2RRYhhwncZYbCOoLxYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ChildID = _t, Test1 = _t, Test2 = _t, Test3 = _t, Test4 = _t, Test5 = _t, Test6 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ChildID", Int64.Type}, {"Test1", type text}, {"Test2", type text}, {"Test3", type text}, {"Test4", type text}, {"Test5", type text}, {"Test6", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ChildID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"ChildID", "Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each [Count] >= 2 and [Value] = "Pass")
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: @Will My solution is totally dynamic ))) you don't have to change any formulas according to the n number of tests )))

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this calculated column: If some students fails more than 2 tests, and there is 3 tests, then only combination leading to "failed state" is 'Fail-Fail-Fail'. Employing this concept, we can write this DAX Code:

Let's say we have a table like this:

[image: Original_Table]

```
Judgement =
IF (
    [Test1] & "-" & [Test2] & "-" & [Test3] = "Fail-Fail-Fail",
    "Fail",
    "Pass"
)
```

Then if we test our code, result It produces:

[image: RESULT_TABLE]